# Como criptografar um arquivo usando c#?

Tags: c#, criptografia

Preciso criar uma função de criptografar arquivos usando o método de Caeser sem usar as funções já prontas da biblioteca do C#. Meu código não funciona para arquivos grandes o computador trava:

```
public static void cesar(string origem, string destino, int chave)
    {
        int cifra;
        byte[] textopuroEmBinario = File.ReadAllBytes(origem);
        byte[] textocriptografadoEmBinario = new byte[textopuroEmBinario.Length];
        BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(File.OpenWrite(destino));
        int i = 0;

            foreach (byte b in textopuroEmBinario)
            {
                    if (b >= 97 && b <= 122){
                    cifra = b + chave; 
                    if (cifra > 122)
                    {
                        cifra = cifra - 26;
                    }
                    textocriptografadoEmBinario[i++] = (byte)cifra;

                }
                else
                {
                    textocriptografadoEmBinario[i++] = b;
                }

            }

            bw.Write(textocriptografadoEmBinario);
            bw.Dispose();
        }
```

Comment: Não entendi, você esta tentando criar uma cifra de César usando binário?

Comment: Estou tentando criptografar qualquer tipo de arquivo usando a cifra de César. O programa funciona mas apenas para arquivos pequenos. Quando colo arquivos grandes o programa trava o computador provavelmente devido ao tamanho do vetor.

Comment: Qual o tamanho do arquivo que faz com que o seu programa trave?

Comment: Não sei bem o tamanho do arquivo, mas é bom ficar atento ao fato de que o framework limita um programa ao uso de 2GB de memória. Recomendo que ao invés de tentar escrever tudo na memória use um buffer com tamanho padrão e quando estiver cheio grave em disco.